# Location of gvm command?

Tags: linux, gvm

I have GVM (Groovy enVironment Manager) installed on my linux system.
I can use the gvm command but `which gvm` OR `alias gvm` produce no results! So, it is neither in path nor an alias. Where is it located? How is it interpreted as command by the shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I realised that it is a shell function. I should have used `type gvm`.